# how can I locally decrypt already sealed secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, google-secret-manager, secrets, poc, sealedsecret

I have a question in regards to using [sealed-secrets](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets)
.

SealedSecrets solution solves the issue we’ve got: be able to store secrets in our version control. However, we want to be able to re-generate the plain secret file from a sealed-secret file (an already encrypted file by kubeseal). Usecase: you go to an existing repo, clone it and you want to see what are the actual secret values from your local machine.

- Is it possible to accomplish this with kubeseal?
- If not, how do you recommend to achieve such behaviour? Maybe an integration with a cloud secret manager, for instance?

As I understand, it goes against the purpose of sealed secrets, given that I want to decrypt outside of the kubernetes controller. But I hope that the use-case makes sense and I get some recommendations on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can only decrypt by downloading sealed-secrets-key. So you can do same as controller does. You have to have access to namespace where Sealed Secrets is installed.

Just check if `kubectl pods` or `kubectl nodes` show resources on right cluster and:

```
kubectl get secret -n sealed-secrets -l sealedsecrets.bitnami.com/sealed-secrets-key -o yaml > sealed-secrets-key.yaml

kubeseal --controller-name=sealed-secrets --controller-namespace=sealed-secrets < /tmp/sealed-secret.yaml --recovery-unseal --recovery-private-key sealed-secrets-key.yaml -o yaml
```

`/tmp/sealed-secret.yaml` is your file that is in version control system. You can also find any sealed secret at: `kubectl get sealedsecrets -A` and pass it.

Reference:

https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets#will-you-still-be-able-to-decrypt-if-you-no-longer-have-access-to-your-cluster